# Adding to a Memory Address Error

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

This doesn't compile in VSC++ 2008.

```
void* toSendMemory2 = toSendMemory + 4;
```

I am at a loss at why, though I am sure it's very stupid of me. :P

Comment: I think it's because the compiler doesn't know how many bytes a "void" takes, but it's been a looong time since I did C++.  Try casting to e.g. a byte *.

Comment: What is `toSendMemory`? How is it declared? What type is it? What error mesage do you get? Please, try posting at least minimum of the critical information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you add `N` to a `T*` the pointer will be incremented by `sizeof(T) * N` bytes. `sizeof(void)` is nonsensical, so pointer arithmetic over `void*` is not allowed.

Comment: Casting as char* with success. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do pointer arithmetic on void pointers. Try casting `(toSendMemory)` to a `(char *)` first (assuming you want to add 4 bytes to it).