# Saving variables sequentially onto the stack

Tags: c++, stack

I'm trying to write a simple program to show how variables can be manipulated indirectly on the stack.  In the code below everything works as planned: even though the address for a is passed in, I can indirectly change the value of c.  However, if I delete the last line of code (or any of the last three), then this no longer applies.  Do those lines somehow force the compiler to put my 3 in variables sequentially onto the stack?  My expectation was that that would always be the case.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void  someFunction(int* intPtr)
{
  // write some code to break main's critical output
  int* cptr = intPtr - 2;
  *cptr = 0;
} 


int main() 
{
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int c = 3;

  someFunction(&a);

  cout << a << endl;
  cout << b << endl;
  cout << "Critical value is (must be 3): " << c << endl;

  cout << &a << endl;
  cout << &b << endl;
  cout << &c << endl; //when commented out, critical value is 3
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to solve a problem using this technique, you should be looking for a new technique.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18843721/841108) to a very similar question....

Comment: A wild guess: For your particular compiler and flags, `&c` might force the address of `c` to be available. Although the compiler still could use an arbitrary value, it probably is conservative enough to create `c` as an object on the stack and use that address for the expression `&c` (or it does not optimize enough, the address is never used to access `c`). When you leave that out, it might use a register or completely eliminate `c` by directly using the value `3` in the cout output operator.

Comment: @tenfour it is for educational purposes only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler can place those wherever and in whatever order it likes in the current stack frame, it may even optimize them out if not used. Just make the compiler do what you want, by using arrays, where pointer arithmetic is safe:

```
int main() 
{
    int myVars[3] = {1,2,3};

    //In C++, one could use immutable (const) references for convenience,
    //which should be optimized/eliminated pretty well.
    //But I would never ever use them for pointer arithmetic.
    int& const a = myVars[0];
    int& const b = myVars[1];
    int& const c = myVars[2];
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Your code causes undefined behaviour.  You can't pass a pointer to an `int` and then just subtract an arbitrary amount from it and expect it to point to something meaningful.  The compiler can put `a`, `b`, and `c` wherever it likes in whatever order it likes.  There is no guaranteed relationship of any kind between them, so you you can't assume `someFunction` will do anything meaningful.

Comment: It's not even guaranteed they (`a`, `b`, `c`) exist as objects IIRC.

Comment: @DyP, that's true.  Since `someFunction` and `main` are in the same translation unit, the compiler can do literally anything with them, as long as the behaviour of the program is consistent with the standard.  It might inline `someFunction`, for example.

Comment: I used the int as an offset based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2376141/564946).

Comment: OK, but your program still isn't valid.

Comment: Not valid in what sense?  It's something I wrote to help improve my understanding of memory allocation.  I saw something unexpected, asked a question, and received helpful explanations.  I would say it has served its purpose.

Answer (score 2):

What you do is undefined behaviour, so anything may happen. But what is probably going on, is that when you don't take the adress of `c` by commenting out `cout << &c << endl;`, the compiler may optimize avay the variable `c`. It then substitutes `cout << c` with `cout << 3`.

Answer (score 1):

As many have answered, your code is wrong since triggering [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18843721/841108) to a similar question.

<sup>In your original code the *optimizing* compiler could place `a`, `b` and `c` in registers, overlap their stack location, etc....</sup>

There are however legitimate reasons for wanting to know what are the location of local variables on the stack (precise garbage collection, introspection and reflection, ...).

The correct way would then to pack these variables in a `struct` (or a `class`) and to have some way to access that structure (for example, linking them in a list, etc.)

So your code might start with

```
void fun (void)
{
   struct {
     int a;
     int b;
     int c;
   } _frame;
#define a _frame.a
#define b _frame.b
#define c _frame.c
   do_something_with(&_frame); // e.g. link it
```

You could also use array members (perhaps even [flexible or zero-length](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) arrays for housekeeping routines), and `#define a _frame.v[0]` etc...

Actually, a good optimizing compiler could optimize that nearly as well as your original code.

<sup>Probably, the type of the `_frame` might be outside of the `fun` function, and you'll generate housekeeping functions for inspecting, or garbage collecting, that `_frame`.</sup>

Don't forget to unlink the frame at end of the routine. Making the frame an object with a proper constructor and destructor definitely helps. The constructor would link the frame and the destructor would unlink it.

For two examples where such techniques are used (both because a [precise garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Precise_vs._conservative_and_internal_pointers) is needed), see my [qish garbage collector](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/qishintro.html) and the (generated C++) code of [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (a domain specific language to extend [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). See also the (generated) C code of [Chicken Scheme](http://www.call-cc.org/) or [Ocaml runtime conventions](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html) (and its `<caml/memory.h>` header).

In practice, such an approach is much more welcome for *generated* C or C++ code (precisely because you will also generate the housekeeping code). If writing them manually, consider at least fancy macros (and templates) to help you. See e.g. [gcc/melt-runtime.h](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/melt-branch/gcc/melt-runtime.h)

I actually believe that this is a deficiency in C. There should be some language features (and compiler implementations) to introspect the stack and to (portably) backtrace on it.

Comment: I think you still have no guarantees about the address of `_frame.b` and `_frame.c` wrt the address of `_frame`. [class.mem]/19 "*Note:* There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct object, but not at its beginning,
as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment."

Comment: Well, it could be an array, or you could generate code to access each member. For instance MELT is generating code to forward each GC-ed values....